# How to check if a ≤ b with an epsilon precision

Tags: java, precision

So I have two doubles, `a` and `b`, and I need to check if `a ≤ b` with the precision of a given epsilon.

So to check if `a == b` I need to do this (`a` and `b` are doubles, `EPSILON` is a final double, in my case 0.001):

```
Math.abs(a - b) < EPSILON
```

My idea as an answer to my own question is:

```
a < EPSILON + b
```

My problem is that with a precision of epsilon, what would be the difference between just less than and less than *or equal* in the final result, maybe someone has a better way to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to write, `a < EPSILON+b`, because if `b` is large, then you might have `b == EPSILON+b`, and then `a < EPSILON+b` would fail if `a` and `b` were exactly equal.

`(a-b) < EPSILON` works.

When comparing numbers with "epsilon precision" you consider numbers to be the same if they are within EPSILON, so "a < b, with epsilon precision" is actually:

`(a-b) <= -EPSILON`

Comment: Do you want to touch on what the OP asked about the difference between `<=` and `<` in this context?

Comment: You made everything much clearer, thank you for this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use BigDecimal, then use it, else:

```
/**
  *@param precision number of decimal digits
  */
public static boolean areEqualDouble(double a, double b, int precision) {
   return Math.abs(a - b) <= Math.pow(10, -precision);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** this post is wrong, see comments. @matttimmens' answer seem legit. (I still have to check corner cases)

**UPDATE 2** I checked and learned. I thought I'd find corner cases like with integers. In Java, `(Integer.MIN_VALUE == ((-Integer.MIN_VALUE)))` is true. This is because integer numbers (as in: non-decimal, non-floating point) have asymmetrical ranges:

- first positive number is 0, first negative number is -1, and thus
- byte: MAX_VALUE is 127, while MIN_VALUE is -128, so `MAX_VALUE != -MIN_VALUE` and `MIN_VALUE != MAX_VALUE`
- also goes for short, int, long

This, mixed together with silent integer overflow, creates problems when working in the extreme corners, especially the off-by-one problem:

```
    final int a = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    final int b = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    final int eps = 1;
    System.out.println("a-b = " + (a - b));
    System.out.println((a - b) < eps);
```

`a-b` results in `1`, and `1 < eps` is false, though we clearly see that a is a lot smaller than b.
This is one corner case where the algorithm would fail on *integers*. Mind: the OP was about *doubles*.

However, floating-point numbers in Java (float, double), or rather, *operations* on them, compensate, and do not allow for overflows to happen:

- `(Double.MAX_VALUE + 1) == Double.MAX_VALUE` holds true
- `(Double.MAX_VALUE + Double.MAX_VALUE) == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` holds true
- `(-Double.MAX_VALUE + -Double.MAX_VALUE) == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` holds true

So before, with integers, the +1 or -1 silent integer overflows caused a problem.
So when adding a +1 (or -1 or *any* small number) to a really large double variable, the change gets lost to rounding. Thus the corner cases play no role here, and @matttimmens' solution `(a-b)<e` is as close to the truth as we can get for floating-point variables, rounding left aside.

**My old, wrong post:**

To counter @matttimmens' reply, run that code:

```
    final double a = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    final double b = Double.MIN_VALUE + 0;
    final double c = Double.MIN_VALUE + 10;
    final double e = 0.001;
    System.out.println("Matches 1: " + ((a - b) < e));
    System.out.println("Matches 2: " + ((b - a) < e));
    System.out.println("Matches 3: " + ((a - c) < e));
    System.out.println("Matches 4: " + ((c - a) < e));
```

Match 3 gives a false result, thus his answer is wrong.

Funny thing is that he thought about vary big numbers, but left the very small numbers unattended.

Comment: Well even your output shows `Matches 3: true`, so that's wrong.

Comment: But a-c = 10... so 10 > e. So the output is wrong. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: a-c = -10, not 10, and -10 < e

Comment: Yes. But that's still not clearing the problem with the precision. `Math.abs(a-b) < EPSILON` might be right to answer the question. But certainly not `(a-b) < EPSILON`

Comment: 'Math.abs(a-b) < EPSILON' is an answer to the question if 'a == b', @matttimmens gave an answer that works for the question if 'a<=b'

Comment: Oh damn... now I see... yes you're right, guys. Shame on me. Updating my post.